# How to use javascript function dateFormat for decades?

Tags: javascript, date-format

How to use Steven Levithan's dateFormat() function to format a date into decade? I have a date May 9th, 2019, 5:46:21 PM. I need to get something like "2010s". Should i create a new mask for it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unfamiliar with Steven Levithan's dateFormat() function, but you can do it with pure JS:

```js
function getDecade(date) {
  return (Math.floor(date.getFullYear() / 10) * 10) + 's';
}

var today = new Date();
var nineties = new Date('1995-12-15');
var independenceDay = new Date('1776-07-04');

console.log(getDecade(today));
console.log(getDecade(nineties));
console.log(getDecade(independenceDay));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have only added 1 row to the original function.

if (mask=="decade") return getDecade(date);

Comment: @Andrey Great! If this answer completely solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.